# Override twitter bootstrap Textbox Glow and Shadows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the Blue glow of the textbox and the border, but i don't know how to override any of the js or the css of it, check [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fadykamal/pE5mQ/62/)

**EDIT 1**

I want to do this because i am using the jquery plugin [Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) and i am using twitter bootstrap also, the plugin uses a hidden textField to add the tags, but when i am using twitter bootstrap it appears as a textbox with glow inside a textbox which is a little bit odd

Comment: Do you have the ability to add a new class?  If so just add a new class with `border:none; box-shadow:none;`

Comment: @jeschafe [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fadykamal/pE5mQ/62/) ,and still nothing

Comment: this helped me: [bootstrap change color of input text border/outline][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097512/bootstrap-change-color-of-input-text-border-outline

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
.simplebox {
  outline: none;
  border: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

You can also override the default Bootstrap setting to use your own colors

```
textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="datetime"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="month"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="week"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="color"]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
  /* IE6-9 */

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
}
```

Comment: it's worth noting that the `<select>` selector isn't included here.

Answer (score 11):

```
input.simplebox:focus {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
}
```

sets to bootstrap unfocused style

Answer (score 8):

if you think you can't handle the css class then simply add style to the textfield

```
<input type="text" style="outline:none; box-shadow:none;">
```

Answer (score 8):

After doing some digging, I think they changed it in the latest bootstrap.  The below code worked for me, its not simple box its form-control that I was using that was causing the issue.

```
input.form-control,input.form-control:focus {
    border:none;
    box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   -moz-transition: none;
   -webkit-transition: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Go to [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), look for @input-border-focus, enter your desired color code, scroll down and click "Compile and Download".

Answer (score 6):

this will remove the border and the focus blue shadow.

```
input.simplebox,input.simplebox:focus {
  border:none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pE5mQ/64/

Answer (score 4):

On bootstrap 3 there is a small top shodow on ios, could be removed with this:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="search"], input[type="password"] {
    -webkit-appearance: caret;
    -moz-appearance: caret; /* mobile firefox too! */
}
```

Got it from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/input-shadows-ipad)

Comment: Looking at the comments from the link you provided, usually better to use 'none' instead of 'caret'.

Answer (score 2):

Vendor prefixes aren't necessary at this point, unless you're supporting legacy browsers, and you could simplify your selectors by just referring to all inputs rather than each of the individual types.

```
input:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control shadow-none">
```

CSS

```
input:focus{
    border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(103, 250, 34, 0.25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far none of the answers helped me out in this thread. What solved it for me was

```
/*Shadow after focus - Overwrites bootstrap5 style for btn classes*/
.btn-check:focus + .btn-primary, 
.btn-primary:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 7px rgba(4,220,93,255);
}
/*Shadow while clicking (Animation) - Overwrites bootstrap5 style for btn classes*/
.btn-check:active + .btn-primary:focus, 
.btn-check:checked + .btn-primary:focus, 
.btn-primary.active:focus, 
.btn-primary:active:focus, 
.show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(10, 102, 37, 0.493);
}
```