# How can I change the border/outline color for input and textarea elements in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the color of bootstrap textbox from the default blue. tried:

```
.input-small,
.input-medium {
    border-color: #E56717;
}
```

Not of much help. Also tried  ":focus"

Comment: Do you want to change the default focus blue color for input smalles right ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I presume you're speaking about the blue glow on focus?  Try this:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, input[type]:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {   
    border-color: rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using bootstrap 3 with LESS, you can set the variable `@input-border-focus`.  This variable can be found in `variables.less`.

Answer (score 0):

To whom visited this page and didn't find a solution, what I did is replacing `-webkit-focus-ring-color` with desired color and it works just fine!

Comment: Won't work on non-webkit browsers. But you know this.

Answer (score 0):

*change box-shadow color*
`input[type]:focus{ box-shadow: none;  }`