# Changing outerglow of bootstrap 3.1.x textarea doesn't seem to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I've found the following question and related answer to change the outerglow of bootstrap input types:

[How can I change the border/outline color for input and textarea elements in Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097512/how-can-i-change-the-border-outline-color-for-input-and-textarea-elements-in-twi)

However, it doesn't seem to work for **textareas**, even though *textarea:focus* is targeted with the CSS. All other input types work correctly. Does anyone know why this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the element which is not being styled is definitely a `<textarea>`.

If it is, perhaps a later style overrides the one you've added - test this by putting `!important` at the end of your new styles e.g:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, input[type]:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {   
    border-color: rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.8)!important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.6)!important;
    outline: 0 none!important;
}
```

If it is being overriden it would be better practice to set a new class on your textarea and apply your desired styles to that class, later in the css than the overriding style.

Comment: Thanks Starscream1984! First of al it was indeed a textarea so that was OK. However, it seems that the style was overridden even though my stylesheet is loaded the last, strange... But I've fixed it with the !important part. I dont want to add a new class to my textarea at this point.