# Bootstrap button disabled outline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm using bootstrap for my project, and don't like the button that has a blue outline when pressed it, how to disabled the blue outline?

[image: bootstrap button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For buttons, you'll need to modify the outline property on focused buttons. This will work for you

```
.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Take a look at this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbNKba) to see it in action. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers add such a border by themselves, then it is hard to remove it. But Bootstrap also adds such a blue border to some form-input elements. There are several questions with answers on how to modify it, for example [How can I change the border/outline color for input and textarea elements in Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097512/how-can-i-change-the-border-outline-color-for-input-and-textarea-elements-in-twi).
In your case, you could set `border: none;` to try to remove it. But as I said, it might also be a browser feature, and not related to Bootstrap, so you just have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Add into your css this code:**

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #ccc;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}
```

(Change border color if you want)