# How to change focus glow of textarea in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the blue glow if the focus on Bootstrap 3 input and textareas.

I tried adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097608/727695)

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, input[type]:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {   
    border-color: rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

to my costum.css but it only change the glow of input fields, not textarea. 
I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16156683/727695),

```
.input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
```

which changed nothing.

I am not a CSS savvy so appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you provide the specific lines of HTML being used and the code that you are trying in the CSS files?

Comment: @RedBassett sure, I update my questoin with the relevant code that I've tried.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {   
    border-color: rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.8) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.6) !important;
    outline: 0 none !important;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. God bless you :) Just curious: Is there any benefit of using rgba() instead of 6digit color codes starting with #?

Comment: Use rgba() if you want some transparent color values. Read about RGBA here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp, and here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color_rgba