# Change the blue outglow on input (checkboxes) (bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, focus, bootstrap-4

I know this question was asked a lot of times and I can guarantee you I tried most of the solutions! My Code is as followed:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="btn-container" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn classic-design">
        <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off"> Player 1
    </label>
</div>
```

This code is inside a Modal of Bootstrap 4, now when I click the button it has this blue outline glow that I'd like to change to another color, lets say red. What I tried so far:

[How to change focus glow of textarea in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574178/how-to-change-focus-glow-of-textarea-in-bootstrap-3)

[How can I change the border/outline color for input and textarea elements in Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097512/how-can-i-change-the-border-outline-color-for-input-and-textarea-elements-in-twi)

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-change-bootstrap-default-input-focus-glow-style.php

[Remove Safari/Chrome textinput/textarea glow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935559/remove-safari-chrome-textinput-textarea-glow)

And so on and so on, I pretty much tried every solution that I found here on StackOverflow, but sadly it didn't work. The only thing that was "close" to what I wanted was this code:

```
label, label:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE !important;
}
```

But the problem with this code is that it creates a permanent red border around all the elements, so yeah and now I'm out of ideas and hope someone can help me.

Note: I didn't try to change the bootstrap css itself, simply because I don't want every focus on my site to change the color, only this specific buttons.

I hope I provided every Info you guys need, I'm still a trainee and started to code just 1 month ago, so please be gentle :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Try outline-color property**

```
input, input:focus {

    outline-color: red;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add .btn-custom class to your button
Change the border color as you wish
Change the rgba value according to the color

```
.btn-custom:focus, .btn-custom:active {
  border-color: #1E824C;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(44, 186, 110),0 0 8px rgba(44, 186, 110);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(44, 186, 110),0 0 8px rgba(44, 186, 110);
}
```